# How get knockout template outer component?

Tags: knockout.js

I changed previous example code and my logic. I need click the button and collapse the from div by element id. Collapse text gets from KO 
arrays, and I want button visible if Array exist. data-bind"visible: exist Array1..2"

```
<div class=«header»>
<!— ko if: typeof Array1 !== 'undefined' —>
    <button data-toggle="collapse" href="#containerLoan<?= $key + 1 ?>» aria-expanded=" false" aria-controls="containerLoan<?= $key ? >">button1</button>
<!-- /ko -->
<!— ko if: typeof Array2 !== 'undefined' —>
<button data-toggle="collapse" href="#containerLoan<?= $key + 2 ?>» 
               aria-expanded=" false
    " aria-controls="containerLoan<?= $key ?>">button2</button>
<!-- /ko -->
</div>

<div class=«loandata» data-bind='component: { name: «test-component", params: { Id: <?= $model->Id ?>} }'></div>

<script type="text/html" id=«test-template">

<div class="collapse multi-collapse" id="containerLoan<?= $key + 1 ?>">
  <div class="card card-body">
    <!-- ko if: Array1.length > 0 -->
      <div>…</div>
    <!-- /ko -->
  </div>
</div>

<div class="collapse multi-collapse" id="containerLoan<?= $key + 2 ?>">
  <div class="card card-body">
    <!-- ko if: Array2.length > 0 -->
      <div>…</div>
    <!-- /ko -->
  </div>
</div>

</script>
```

In *.ts 
    namespace Test.One {

```
export class TestViewModel {
…
Array1: KnockoutObservable<Product> = ko.computed(() => { … return …; }
Array2: KnockoutObservable<Product> = ko.computed(() => { … return …; }

private fetch(id: number): void {
$.getJSON(…)
}

    constructor(params: { Id: number }) {
        this.Id(params.Id);
        this.fetch(params.Id);
    }
export class ViewModel {
    constructor() {
        ko.components.register(‘test-component', {
            viewModel: params => {
                return new TestViewModel(params);
            },
            template:{
    element : 
                 'hint-loan-product-template'
},
        });
    }
}

export let viewModelObject = new ViewModel();
ko.cleanNode(document.getElementById(‘test-area’));
ko.applyBindings(viewModelObject);//,    document.getElementById(‘test-area'));
```

}

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is to explicitly pass a reference to the `isVisible` observable via the component's `params`. This way, you don't create a hard dependency that forces the component to only be used within binding contexts that contain a certain property.

Here's an example, using some component from [the knockout docs](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-binding.html)

- The outer viewmodel contains a visibility control property: `outerIsVisible`
- When creating the component, we tell it which observable controls the visibility
- The component's viewmodel has its own `isVisible` which references the one in `params`
- The component's view references its own viewmodel's property, of which we can be sure it's always defined.

```js
ko.components.register('message-editor', {
    viewModel: function(params) {
        this.isVisible = params.isVisible;
        this.text = ko.observable(params && params.initialText || '');
    },
    template: `<div data-bind="visible: isVisible">
      Message: <input data-bind="textInput: text" />
      (length: <span data-bind="text: text().length"></span>)
    </div>`
});
 
ko.applyBindings({
  outerIsVisible: ko.observable(true)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<label>
  <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: outerIsVisible">
  Show message editor
</label>

<div data-bind='component: {
    name: "message-editor",
    params: { 
      initialText: "Hello, world!",
      isVisible: outerIsVisible
    }
}'></div>
```

Comment: thanks, I changed the my example in post and question

Comment: Your new example can be solved by using the same approach: pass references to `Array1` and `Array2` to the component. Of course, you can also use `$parent.Array1` in your component template, but this breaks the whole idea of using components.